# Есть ли смысл писать JS код в .HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Часто наблюдаю на различных сайтах, что разработчики некоторые куски кода записывают прямо в .HTML.
Зачем?

- Также иногда делают с CSS кодом, записывая его том же html через атрибут "style". Догадываюсь, что все дело в каскадности, и чтобы определенные свойства 100% были применены и не были переписаны, их записывают инлайном. 
  Поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/hello-world

Answer (score 2):

Если технология предоставляет какую-то возможно, то человек может брать и пользоваться ей, без всякой действительно важной причины. К примеру, разработчику может быть банально лень создавать отдельный файл и правильно прописывать обработку кода.

С CSS немного сложнее, это действительно может делаться для управления каскадностью, когда на какой-то странице надо переопределить общее поведение всех элементов на другое. Ну или же см. абзац выше для JS.

Хотя, конечно, лучше всё держать на своих местах в отдельных файлах.

Comment: ещё пара примеров к дополнению: через сервер приходят фотографии, которые удобно вставлять через инлайновые стили в html, через SSR, куски кода js в html могут быть просто глобальными переменными (вставляемые через php, к примеру), которые приходят с сервера, текст, к примеру, а уже из самого файла js можно забрать эту переменную

Answer (score 2):

Я в некоторые проекты ставлю часть CSS прямо в хед. Делаю так в случае если у меня вверху страницы многоуровневое меню, а файл стилей большой. Так вот чтобы это меню не разваливалось на этапе загрузки (например при плохом интернете) - критически важные стили, которые используются для прорисовки первого скрина контента я ставлю в хед. Также это положительно сказывается на результатах всяких тестов-валидаторов, типа Lighthouse.

Еще, могут быть условия, при которых проще написать кусок jQuery прямо в html и при этом не создавать еще один запрос на сервер за файлом. Это если нужно свести количество запросов к минимуму, а на этой страницу не используются скрипты больше.